# EF 5 - Can column mapping names be changed?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I'm using VS 2012 with the latest version of EF 5.  In my .edmx file I have a few entities created from my database views.  (My project is setup database-first)

I would like to change a few of the mapped column names (I don't have control over the database in this case).  I changed one of the names and have it mapped to the correct column. The project builds OK.

When I run it, I get the error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Model.User'. A
>   member of the type, 'MyDatabaseColumnName', does not have a
>   corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

I am calling a stored procedure that returns all of the columns from my view that was used to create the entity.  Did I miss a step here?

Comment: How did you change it? It appears that you change it in the storage definition and this has to actually match the store. What you want to do is to change in the conceptual layer and the mapping layer. If you use the designer you can just rename a property on the model and it should take care of doing this for you.

Comment: I changed it using the designer, in the properties of the entity object.  I also thought that was all I had to do.

Comment: And just another note. If I do update my database View with the new name, everything works OK.